# Consolidating column values based on another column value

Tags: excel

I'm looking to do the following in Excel:

I have a table and want to write a function or formula to look at the values in one column and where they are identical, take the value in another column and concatenate it to the column value for the first record it found (in a new column).

For example:

```
ADDRESS                         PAGE         NEW COLUMN
1 810 ANDERSON TERR 1817-2     1817-2
10 1940 HILLSIDE DR 1315-42    1315-42
101 TRANQUILLE RD              1518-53     1518-53 1517-30
101 TRANQUILLE RD              1517-30     
1020 HILLSIDE DR               1417-111    1417-111 1417-112
1020 HILLSIDE DR               1417-112 
10285 DALLAS DR                1330-10     1330-10 1330-3
10285 DALLAS DR                1330-3   
1051 PINE SPRINGS RD           2218-46     2218-46 2218-18 2218-31 2217-6 2218-32
1051 PINE SPRINGS RD           2217-18  
1051 PINE SPRINGS RD           2218-31  
1051 PINE SPRINGS RD           2217-6   
1051 PINE SPRINGS RD           2218-32
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!!

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I would sort the table on the column in question, then you get all rows with the same column value after each other. On the sorted table, you can then use a function like

> =IF('column value' = 'previous column value', 'concatenate values', '')

If you always need to concatenate the FIRST value found, you can make another column that always contains just the first found value for a set of rows that belong together and concatenate with that.

More precise:

1) Sort table
2) Assuming Address in column A and Page in column B, add this formula in column C (and copy down):

> =IF(A2=A1,C1& " " & B2, B2)

This gives exactly the values in your example:

> ADDRESS    PAGE    NEW
>
> 1 ANDERSON 1817-2  1817-2
>
> 10 HILLSIDE    1315-42 1315-42
>
> 101 TRANQUILLE 1518-53 1518-53
>
> 101 TRANQUILLE 1517-30 1518-53 1517-30
>
> 1020 HILLSIDE  1417-111    1417-111
>
> 1020 HILLSIDE  1417-112    1417-111 1417-112
>
> 10285 DALLAS   1330-10 1330-10
>
> 10285 DALLAS   1330-3  1330-10 1330-3
>
> 1051 PINE  2218-46 2218-46
>
> 1051 PINE  2217-18 2218-46 2217-18
>
> 1051 PINE  2218-31 2218-46 2217-18 2218-31
>
> 1051 PINE  2217-6  2218-46 2217-18 2218-31 2217-6
>
> 1051 PINE  2218-32 2218-46 2217-18 2218-31 2217-6 2218-32

If you do not want the intermediate concatenations you have to hide column C and make another one which copies the value of column C when the value in column A changes.

Comment: Thanks Eye - while that works for comparing 2 records that have the same value, it is unknown how many records I need to compare - sometimes there are more than 2 records with the same value - needs to ba a variable of some kind...any other thoughts?

Comment: And my apologies for the formatting of my table not coming through properly in my post!

Comment: That does also work for more than two records - or don't I understand your question right?

Comment: Alternatively you can of course just write a function that loops over the contents of the first column (I still would sort it first, then you can go without a dictionary for remembering which values you already had) and build up the concatenated string. But this is way slower than using a formula directly in excel cells...

Comment: I'm probably thinking more along the lines of a function...  The example you provided was great but only compares 2 rows at a time...again, my sample table didn't come through properly format-wise.  How are you with looping/functions - it's been awhile for me using them but with a bit of sample code I think I can figure it out.  Again, need to compare x amount of rows which is variable in my data and ranges from 2 identical rows to as many as 30 identical rows that need to be compared...  Thanks again!

Comment: Got it - thanks a bunch!!  I'll try the function as well, for my own knowledge but your formula should fit the bill!!

Answer (score 0):

And as a function:

```
Sub Combine()

    Dim rwNumber As Integer
    Dim value As String
    Dim oldValue As String
    Dim concatenatedString As String

    'Sort the table
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A2:C14")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    For rwNumber = 2 To 100
       'gets value of first cell
       value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rwNumber, 1).value
       If value = oldValue Then
        concatenatedString = concatenatedString + " " + ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rwNumber, 2).value
       Else
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rwNumber - 1, 3).value = concatenatedString
            concatenatedString = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rwNumber, 2).value
       End If
       oldValue = value
    Next rwNumber
End Sub
```

Or something like that :-)